# What are debuff exploits until lvl 4/5 for a warlord / Role of warlord

Tags: dnd-4e, warlord

I keep hearing about warlords being the best buffers/debuffers in the game. I have a tactical warlord with Inspiring Word, Commander's Strike, Wolf Pack Tactics, Warlord's Favor (+2 Power Bonus), and Hold the Line (+2 power bonus to AC) as exploits. Somehow, this seems quite measly to me.

What am I doing wrong? Is my role really to get into the fray and deal damage, or is it to stay back?

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To the extent that they apply at all, "buff" and "debuff" are the jobs of two different roles — leaders, like the Warlord, improve your fellow PCs while controllers hinder the enemies. Which appeals to you more?

Comment: What weapon do your wield? If you wield a pole arm its a bit different then if you wield a sword or axe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warlords are great. Typically you want to get into the thick of things and mix things up in melee. (You can go archer, but it isn't the best class for it.) If you want some awesome suggestions on powers and things, I would be remiss if I did not refer you to the [D&D Char Op Warlord page](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2550946). The folks who put these together have a lot of great ideas and even cover some basic tactics.

You specialize in moving your allies around the battlefield (Wolf Pack Tactics) and giving your striker and defender extra attacks (Commander's Strike). For the defender, it's more marks; for your striker, it's more opportunities to do major damage.

*Warlord's Favor* is useful as a power bonus. At this level, a +2 (to hit and damage I believe) is awful nice to have: it's an extra 10% chance to hit and extra damage to boot. That's very nice.

*Hold the Line* is essentially a debuff: by reducing your enemies' chance to hit by 10% (if they target AC) you are reducing the average damage they are able to put out. It's a bit suboptimal, but if your group stays in a tight group it can be useful.

A +2 bonus on encounters in early levels is quite useful. Anything more and you have to take a disadvantage. (Not your thing; taking penalties is more of a Bravura Warlord's niche).